# Методы с одинаковыми сигнатурами в C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, language-lawyer, signature

Предположим, есть такой класс.

```
public class SomeClass<T>
{
    public void DoSomething(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething(int x) called");
    }

    public void DoSomething(T x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething(T x) called");
    }
}
```

А также вот такой фрагмент кода

```
var someObj = new SomeClass<int>();
```

У меня два вопроса.

1) У закрытого типа `SomeClass<int>` получаются два метода с одинаковой сигнатурой. Тогда почему компилятор же не ругается на них?

2) Скажем, если вызвать

```
someObj.DoSomething(0);
```

Данный фрагмент кода пишет "DoSomething(int x) called". Почему был вызван именно вариант с целочисленным параметром, а не с обобщённым параметром?

Comment: Какого плана ответ Вы хотите увидеть? *Потому что так написано в спецификации языка (пункт ...)* — подойдёт? Или Вы хотите знать почему в спецификации написано именно так, а не иначе? P.S. Вызвать метод с обобщённым параметром можно так: `public static class SomeClassExtension { public static void DoSomethingGeneric<T>(this SomeClass<T> obj, T x) => obj.DoSomething(x); }`, `someObj.DoSomethingGeneric(0)`.

Comment: @PetSerAl Зачем такой тон? Мне, к примеру, тоже интересно. Вопрос не только в том, как вызвать, а и чем обусловлено такое поведение. Если Вы знаете пункт из спецификации языка, то скажите.

Comment: @Igor Какой *такой*? Я просто задаю уточняющий вопрос. Я, например, просто не хочу тратить своё время на поиск нужного пункта спецификации, если это не то, что нужно автору.

Comment: P.S. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382

Comment: Статьи по теме: [Eric Lippert: closer is better](https://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/), [Jon Skeet: overloading](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx)

Comment: Связанные вопросы: [Generic overload resolution](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3678703/2881286), [Which C# method overload is chosen?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32892243/2881286), [Generic methods and method overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3679562/2881286)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Выдержка из спецификации (пункт 7.5.3.2):

> ...
>   In case the parameter type sequences {P1, P2, …, PN} and {Q1, Q2, …, QN} are equivalent (i.e. each Pi has an identity conversion to the corresponding Qi), the following tie-breaking rules are applied, in order, to determine the better function member.
>
> • If MP is a non-generic method and MQ is a generic method, then MP is better than MQ.
>   ...

по русски это звучит примерно так:

> Если последовательности параметров эквивалентны, применяются следующие правила выбора лучшего метода:
>
> - Если метод Mp не обобщенный и метод Mq обобщенный, то Mp лучше чем Mq

Там еще много правил отсева, но для этого случая остальные правила несущественны.

Ок, откуда ноги растут выяснили, данное поведение прописано в спецификации. Как это выглядит в реализации? Давайте заглянем в скомпилированный код и сравним обобщенный и не обобщенный методы. Я использую ILSpy, но можно воспользоваться любым знакомым инструментом, например ILDasm.

```
// Methods
.method public hidebysig 
    instance void DoSomething (
        int32 x
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x205a
    // Code size 11 (0xb)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldstr "DoSomething(int x) called"
    IL_0005: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_000a: ret
} // end of method SomeClass`1::DoSomething

.method public hidebysig 
    instance void DoSomething (
        !T x
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2066
    // Code size 11 (0xb)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldstr "DoSomething(T x) called"
    IL_0005: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_000a: ret
} // end of method SomeClass`1::DoSomething
```

как видите, код обобщенного метода класса остался обобщенным после компиляции (обратите внимание на `!` перед именем типа во втором методе).

На вопрос почему выбор происходит так, а не наоборот ответили. Теперь немного о возможных причинах такой реализации и правил выбора. Возможных, потому что я не являюсь разработчиком данной спецификации, но из общей логики некоторые выводы сделать можно.

1. В обобщенных методах вы ограничены в применении языковых средств к переменным обобщенного типа. Например нельзя применять операторы сравнения, кроме проверок на равенство и не равенство, т.к. мы не можем гарантировать что они реализованы в типе, для которого будет вызван обобщенный метод. Соответственно при наличии подходящего не обобщенного метода, с большой вероятностью он может быть реализован более эффективно за счет использования специализированных средств конкретного типа.
2. Перед вызовом обобщенного метода, компилятор должен заменить обобщенные типы на реальные. Эти действия не требуются при использовании не обобщенных методов, а значит даже в тривиальных случаях, когда эффективность методов одинакова, стоимость вызова обобщенного метода незначительно, но выше.

Получается что обобщенные методы немного теряют производительность, а что в замен? Ведь у нас есть общий корень - тип `object`, к которому также можно привести любой другой тип. Я вижу это так:

1. При использовании обобщенных методов не используется приведение типов как в случае использование `object`, а это выигрыш в скорости, особенно для ValueType типов, т.к. отсутствует боксинг.
2. При использовании обобщенных типов можно быть уверенным, что если у двух переменных указан один и тот же обобщенный тип. то при выполнении их типы также будут одинаковы, в отличие от переменных типа `object`, внутри которых может лежать что угодно, и требуются дополнительные проверки для исключения ошибок во время выполнения.
3. При использовании обобщенных типов, мы можем использовать уточнения или ограничения, кому как нравится, и явно указать: класс это или структура, наличие конструктора (пока только конструктор по умолчанию), базовый тип, а также список интерфейсов, которые должны быть реализованы в типах, которые разрешено использовать в конкретном обобщенном методе или классе. Этот вариант, как и предыдущий, для типа `object` можно реализовать только путем дополнительных проверок и увеличения объема необходимого кода.

Естественно я могу ошибаться насчет истинных причин конкретно такой реализации. Естественно списки преимуществ и недостатков далеко не полные. Но я считаю что этого достаточно для общего понимания почему обобщенные типы и все с ними связанное такие, какие есть и применения их по назначению и с пользой для дела.

---

PS: Все, кроме цитаты из спецификации и IL-кода, является моим личным мнением, если вы с ним не согласны, то мы можем обсудить это в [**чате**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50936/discussion-between-vadim-ovchinnikov-and-rdorn) или вы можете написать собственный ответ на данный вопрос и изложить свою точку зрения.

Отдельное спасибо **[@Vadim Ovchinnikov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/220571/vadim-ovchinnikov)** за критику предыдущего варианта.

Comment: Честно говоря, я не понимаю, где здесь ответ почему. У вас ответ выглядит таким: первая часть ответа а ля "так скомпилировалось" (что, в принципе, нам и без IL ясно) , вторая — оправдание работы компилятора, причём для меня неясное. А если бы вызывалось наоборот, то чем бы это нам мешало *"создавать обобщенные методы-расширения, в частности LiNQ"*?

Comment: *"Следующий по логике вопрос - а зачем тогда вообще указывать точный тип при использовании обобщенных методов, если они в любом случае остаются обобщенными? - чтобы иметь возможность контроля на этапе компиляции, а не кидаться исключениями в рантайме."* Вообще не понял аргумента.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov на вопрос почему, ответ как раз в IL-коде, в таблице методов класса есть две сигнатуры, одна с конкретным типом, другая с обощенным, который формируется динамически, для перегруженного метода сначала ищется полное совпадение сигнатуры с вызовом, и только потом то, что может теоретически подойти, т.е. в данном случае обобщенный. А почему так скомпилировалось - в спецификацию

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov позже поправлю спорные формулировки, что бы читались однозначно, действительно некоторые вещи написаны не удачно, но суть в том, что для обобщенных методов используется один и тот же код с одной и той же сигнатурой всегда, не зависимо от значений типа-параметра

Comment: IL-код — это не причина, это следствие намерений разработчиков компилятора. Это если бы на вопрос "почему дует ветер?", я бы ответил "потому что деревья шатаются". А вопрос "почему" требует разъяснений *причины*. Это должна быть либо спецификация, либо утверждения разработчиков платформы .NET (например, в блогах), либо *веские* причины именно такого подхода.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov ок, IL это следствие спецификации, и при этом причина конкретного поведения C# кода, с этим надеюсь вы спорить не собираетесь?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50936/discussion-between-vadim-ovchinnikov-and-rdorn).