# Generic или не Generic

Tags: c#, .net, clr

В обсуждении моего [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609412/198316) на [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/609392/198316) возник один спорный момент.

Допустим имеем обобщенный класс и три метода в нем:

```
class SomeClass<T>
{
    //не обобщенный метод
    public void DoSomething(int x) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("True non generic method"); 
    }
    //не обобщенный метод с параметром обобщенного типа класса
    public void DoSomething(T x)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Indirectly generic method"); 
    }
    //явно  обобщенный метод
    public void DoSomething<U>(U x)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("True generic method"); 
    }
}
```

Собственно вопрос - является ли не обобщенный метод, с параметром обобщенного типа класса, обобщенным методом?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Всё же, как вы догадались, ответ **необобщённый** (non-generic). Потому что есть определение, что такое обобщённый метод и всё.

Метод считается обобщённым, когда у него есть **свой** *параметр типа*. Если у него его нет, то это необобщённый метод.

У обобщённого типа метод может заимствовать параметр типа для возвращаемого значения и/или для типа параметра (не путайте *тип параметра* с *параметром типа*, хотя этот каламбур, наверняка, наводит путаницу), но это не сделает его обобщённым, если у метода нету своего *параметра типа*.

И ваши исследования генерируемого IL совершенно не противоречат мои доводам.
Но я бы всё равно не смешивал терминологию языка программирования и детали его реализации. Я не считаю это корректным.

---

Подкину тему для размышлений: иногда [невиртуальные методы вызываются как виртуальные](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2008/07/03/c-generates-virtual-calls-to-non-virtual-methods-as-well/). Просто генерируется инструкция `callvirt` в некоторых случаях для невиртуальных методов и всё. Можно было бы также спросить "Может их следует называть неявно виртуальные?" (*Но тут скорей очевидно, что это просто делать реализации*).

---

#### Смущение для разработчиков

Но для начинающих (и не только) разработчиков — это, по крайней мере поначалу, странно. К примеру, все привычные члены `Dictionary` необобщённые: `Add(TKey, TValue)`, `ContainsKey(TKey)`, `TryGetValue(TKey, TValue)`, `Remove(TKey)` и т.д.. И это многих удивляет, даже иногда тех, кто пользовался годами этим словарём. Тип обобщённый, но методы — нет. У `List` дела обстоят интересно: у него только один обобщённый метод `ConvertAll<TOutput>(Converter<T, TOutput>)`, остальные — нет.

Comment: public void DoSomething(T x)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Indirectly generic method"); 
    }
и 
  //явно  обобщенный метод
    public void DoSomething<U>(U x)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("True generic method"); 
    }
равносильны,просто первый "неявно обобщенный".

Comment: @CSharpUser Я не понимаю вашего комментария. Вы хотите что-то оспорить или мне доказать?

Answer (score 7):

В [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx) такие методы называются не обобщенными методами обобщенного класса, что ни чем не лучше моей формулировки в вопросе. В спецификации такой вариант тоже не рассматривается отдельно. Ок, раз ни где ни чего конкретно не написано спросим у самой CLR, в конце концов именно ей исполнять все что мы понаписали.

Итак, начнем с объявления класса

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit ConsoleApplication.SomeClass`1<T>
```

Интересный момент: **`1** -  цифры после апострофа означают число параметров типа, но главная задача этой прибавки - расширение имени класса. Таким образом у нас может быть два класса с одинаковым именем и разным количеством обобщающих параметров включая не обобщенный класс без параметров.

Объявления методов (тело опускаю, т.к. не важно в данном случае):

Не обобщенный метод

```
.method public hidebysig 
    instance void DoSomething (
        int32 x //тип указан явно
    ) cil managed
```

Явно обобщенный метод

```
.method public hidebysig 
    instance void DoSomething<U> (
        !!U x //обратите внимание на два восклицательных знака
    ) cil managed
```

Два восклицательных знака сообщают JITу что конкретный тип нужно искать в обобщающих параметрах метода

Не обобщенный метод с параметром обобщенного типа класса

```
.method public hidebysig 
    instance void DoSomething (
        !T x //тут только один восклицательный знак
    ) cil managed
```

Один восклицательный знак сообщает JITу что конкретный тип нужно искать в обобщающих параметрах класса.

Ок, уже что-то, теперь взглянем на то, как эти методы вызываются:

Не обобщенный метод

```
call instance void class ConsoleApplication.SomeClass`1<int32>::DoSomething(int32)
```

тип параметра указывается явно

Явно обобщенный метод

```
call instance void class ConsoleApplication.SomeClass`1<int32>::DoSomething<int32>(!!0)
```

тип параметра указывается ссылкой на параметр с индексом 0 в списке обобщающих параметров метода

Не обобщенный метод с параметром обобщенного типа класса

```
call instance void class ConsoleApplication.SomeClass`1<int32>::DoSomething(!0)
```

тип параметра указывается ссылкой на параметр с индексом 0 в списке обобщающих параметров класса

Получается, что в текущей реализации мы имеем два вида обобщенных методов - явные и неявные. В обоих случаях JITу потребуются дополнительные действия при компиляции данных методов для разрешения типов, т.к. в обоих случаях при вызове указана только ссылка на элемент списка обобщающих параметров.

**Итого для конкретной реализации компилятора/JIT/VM:**

1. Есть два типа методов - **обобщенные** и **не обобщенные**.
2. **Обобщенные** методы могут быть обобщенными **явно** и **неявно**.
3. Приоритет при выборе перегруженного метода при прочих равных условиях:

   - не обобщенный
   - неявно обобщенный
   - явно обобщенный

В спецификации эту информацию найти можно, но только косвенно, прямых упоминаний нет, видимо понадеялись на логику читающих.

---

PS: Если есть другое объяснение, с удовольствием его прочитаю в вашем ответе.

Comment: "В обоих случаях CLR потребуются дополнительные действия при вызове данных методов для разрешения типов" - нет, CLR же не интерпретатор. На самом деле там указана не "ссылка на элемент списка обобщающих параметров", а на конкретный methodDesc c конкретными типами. При компиляции вызывающего метода JIT полезет в MT, достанет оттуда адрес отJITченного генерика (конкретный, для value type, или общий на все reference) и вставит call <адрес> в место вызова. Т.е. есть один (быстрый) поиск реализации под конкретный тип в момент JIT. При самом вызове никаких потерь или дополнительных телодвижений нет.

Comment: я к тому, что сейчас ваш ответ как-бы намекает что генерики создают проблемы с производительностью. хотя они как раз их решают :)

Comment: @PashaPash тяжелая артиллерия подтянулась =) для того и писал, чтобы выяснить все спорные моменты =) спасибо